# Помогите разобраться с синтаксисом php в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне нужно проверять пост по его типу и если он совпадает - выводить определенный шаблон.

Вот код single.php

```html
$items = get_posts( $args ); //все товары
$item_ids = array(); //только id-шники товаров
foreach($items as $item):
 if(!in_array($item->ID, $item_ids)) $item_ids[] = $item->ID;
  endforeach;
 if(in_array($post->ID, $item_ids)): //если текущий пост является товаром то выводим блок о товаре
?>
      
тут один шаблон, стандартный
      
<?php if (is_single() && is_post_type('post_type')){ ?>

здесь я пытаюсь осуществлять проверку по типу поста, и у меня не получается. Уверен что проблема в синтаксисе

<?php } ?>
      
         
<?php else: //Если текущий пост не товар, то выводим просто контент поста?>
      
      тут второй шаблон
      
<?php endif;?>
```

Этот код я добавил в свой functions.php для проверки по типу поста (инфу взял [отсюда](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/if-is-custom-post-type)  ). Отдельно этот код работает, но интегрировать в существующий не получается.

```html
function is_post_type($type){
    global $wp_query;
    if($type == get_post_type($wp_query->post->ID)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить вот эту конструкцию

```
if (is_single() && is_post_type('post_type')) {...}
```

вот этой

```
$post_type = get_post_type($post->ID);
if ($post_type == 'post_type') {...}
```

В single.php проверка `is_single()` избыточна, т. к. вы уже находитесь в шаблоне для страницы поста

ps и да, у вас ошибка в синтаксисе. В конструкции `if ... else` используются либо фигурные скобки, либо `endif;`, а не оба вместе. Т. е. либо

`if (условие) {...} else {...}`

либо

`if (условие): ... else: ... endif;`

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `if (is_single() && is_post_type('post_type'))` используйте `if (is_singular('post_type'))`